# send_file vs html5 download attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, cross-browser

It looks like the [HTML5 download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is supported on every browser now, and I was wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages to using this instead of creating a link and using `send_file` in a controller with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

`send_file` is both more versatile and more efficient.

Its main advantage is that it uses the [X-Sendfile](https://mattbrictson.com/accelerated-rails-downloads) response header. What that does is offload the streaming process of the file from Ruby to the server (e.g. Nginx or Apache) which is optimized for high-throughput content delivery.

Plain 'download' links save the target regardless of what's displayed on it. This could be a problem if, for example, the target is session-protected, and the session expires before you click the link. You'd end up saving the login page without knowing it. With `send_file` you can dynamically initiate the download if the session is ok, or redirect to the login page otherwise.

`send_file` also lets you specify a meaningful file name dynamically, so if your link points to, say, /users/42, you could set the download name to be "John Smith.csv" instead of the cryptic "42".